# How to change the default sender id in AWS Cognito messages to verify mobile number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I am using AWS Cognito User Pool for user sign up. I am using phone number as the attribute and I have set up verification of mobile number and enabled Multi-Factor Authentication.

I get messages from AWS and its getting verified and everything is working fine. But the sender of the message is "AXNOTICE".

I need to change "AXNOTICE" to my business id. I tried changing "Default sender ID" in "Text messaging preferences" of SNS Dashboaard but this didn't work.

Please let me know whether this is the correct place to change or do I need to change somewhere else.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AWS does not support sender id in india https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

Comment: Thanks Varnit for the information.

Comment: i have updated the answer please accept the answer if it solved your problem so that others may find it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS currently does not support custom sender id in some countries to find the list of countries that are supported by aws click on the below link

[AWS custom sender id supported regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late, but maybe useful for someone who is sending SMS where SenderId is allowed (e.g. UK):

It is possible to set a default SenderId in Simple Notification Service(SNS) which will then be used by Cognito when sending SMS.

- Open SNS
- Expand "Mobile" menu and click "Text Messaging (SMS)"
- Scroll down to "Text messaging preferences" and click "Edit"
- Set "Default sender ID"
- Click "Save Changes"

Cognito will now send the SMS using the specified SenderId.

(Note, things may have changed since this question was answered it seems India does allow SenderId, but requires a reserved SenderId to be used, which is expensive ~£800/month. See https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id.html

Some countries do not allow SenderId: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-sender-ids.html )